# TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable when trying to forward pass a NN

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
class ModelClass(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModelClass, self).__init__()
        self.a = Input(shape=[2])
        self.b = Dense(2)(self.a)

    def call(self,data):
        d = self.a(data)
        y = self.b(d)

        return y

prediction_class = ModelClass()
data = np.array([1.0,2],dtype="float32")
prediction_class(tf.convert_to_tensor(data[None, :])) # line 30 (say)
```

When i was running line 30 it say

```
> TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
> <ipython-input-104-814bbab065ca> in call(self, data)
>      10         # x = self.input_data(data)
>      11         print("Hereh")
> ---> 12         d = self.a(data)
>      13         y = self.b(d)
>      14
```

But i dont know why ? plus i am new to this So don't find where it is writen that call method of model class will run automatically after me saying  **`prediction_class()`**

Comment: I was using wrong imports for Model. It should be `tensorflow.python`

Answer (score 1):

```
class ModelClass(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModelClass, self).__init__()
        self.b = Dense(2)

    def call(self, data):
        y = self.b(data)

        return y

prediction_class = ModelClass()
data = np.array([1,2],dtype="float32")
prediction_class(tf.convert_to_tensor(data[None, :]))
```